# Create element names dynamically and group data while parsing one xml to another xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to transform the data received in one XML into another XML file using XSLT.

The data in XML to be parsed contains "_" (underscore). I want to generate elements from this XML and group them based on the names extracted from element names.

**XML to be parsed**

```
<data>
   <fruits_apple_red>1</fruits_apple_red>
   <animal_carnivorous_cat_tiger_white>5</animal_carnivorous_cat_tiger_white>
   <animal_reptiles_lizard>3</animal_reptiles_lizard>
   <animal_carnivorous_lion>4</animal_carnivorous_lion>
   <fruits_orange_orange>2</fruits_orange_orange>
   <animal_carnivorous_cat_hyena>6</animal_carnivorous_cat_hyena>
</data>
```

**XML needed**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
   <fruits>
      <apple_red>1</apple_red>
      <orange_orange>2</orange_orange>
   </fruits>
   <animal>
      <carnivorous>
         <cat>
            <tiger_white>5</tiger_white>
            <hyena>6</hyena>
         </cat>
         <lion>4</lion>
      </carnivorous>
      <reptiles_lizard>3</reptiles_lizard>
   </animal>
</data>
```

I'm new to XSLT and I have tried using XSLT string functions(substring) but unable to get XML in this format. The problem I faced is that the element names are dynamic and we need to extract names out the element names.
So, I can't really write code with name "data" as root element or "animal/fruits" as 2nd level element names.

Another thing that we need is the multi level (like for animal) although I feel that this may require some hardcoded checks(using xsl:if statement) at some stage. But the point is too group the data multi-level as far as possible.

Could anyone please let me know how can this can be done either using XSLT.

**Note:** This is sample data but real data contains element names separated by "_". Client needs it this way so that they can directly bind the required part to respective grid.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible in XSLT 2 or 3 using a recursive function and `xsl:for-each-group group-by` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element()*">
      <xsl:param name="elements" as="element()*"/>
      <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$elements" group-by="tokenize(local-name(), '_')[$level]">
          <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="not(current-group()[2])">
                  <xsl:element name="{string-join(tokenize(local-name(), '_')[position() ge $level], '_')}">
                      <xsl:apply-templates/>
                  </xsl:element>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:element name="{current-grouping-key()}">
                      <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group(), $level + 1)"/>
                  </xsl:element>
              </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="data">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(*, 1)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That results in (see http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMeh)

```
<data>
   <fruits>
      <apple_red>1</apple_red>
      <orange_orange>2</orange_orange>
   </fruits>
   <animal>
      <carnivorous>
         <cat>
            <tiger_white>5</tiger_white>
            <hyena>6</hyena>
         </cat>
         <lion>4</lion>
      </carnivorous>
      <reptiles_lizard>3</reptiles_lizard>
   </animal>
</data>
```

so it has the right elements although the order is different, I could not infer from your posting what determines the order. It shouldn't be too difficult however to add some other ordering, if necessary by pushing the result of the function to another mode that establishes the order you want.

As for an explanation: The function gets the child elements `*` of the `data` elements as the initial input and uses `for-each-group` recursively by tokenizing the `local-name()` (e.g. `fruits_apple_red`) of each element on the separator `_` to get a sequence of name tokens (e.g. `fruits`, `apple`, `red`) and using the first token (e.g. `fruits`) as the grouping key on the first call (with the `[$index]` as `[1]` predicate) and then the second token (e.g. `apple`) on the second call and so on. Recursion is stopped when there is only one element in a group as I inferred that to be the condition why e.g. `apple_red` is not further split.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks a lot for the answer. It is working correctly for this example. However, it is not giving the correct answer when I tried for the actual data. It will be really helpful if you could explain the code written in xslt so that I can make the relevant changes so as to make it work for actual data.

Comment: @maverick, I have added some explanation in the answer but you would need to share information/sample data on how the input and output you have differs from the sample you have shown so far in the question. If you need further help then please do that by editing the question with the variants of the input data and result you have.

Comment: Hi Martin, I have added subset of data. Tested this data against this xslt but it doesn't makes any changes as it was doing with previous example. As you see that some are splitted till one level, some till 2 levels while some till 3 or more. Obviously this cannot be generic since levels are not fixed for all first level elements. So, we may need some hardcoding eg. variables, we collect those, then if next type is cc or all then further break else add it directly under variable. Same is case for providers where levels can go if request/response is there else it breaks will previous one only.

Comment: The implemented algorithm can be applied to the new sample by changing the `match` attribute, as in http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMeh/1. Obviously that doesn't help if some elements need a completely different treatment.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin for providing the solution.

Comment: Hi Martin, I have one more query. I tried this solution in .NET code. However, it turned out that .NET is still having XSLT 1.0 processor and can't work on 2.0 or 3.0 version. It actually gave errors. Could you please let me know if this can be done in XSLT 1.0. Any pointers to that will be very helpful.

Comment: It is true that the Microsoft .NET framework as provided by Microsoft only includes an XSLT 1 processor but that doesn't prevent you from using XSLT 2 or 3 with .NET code as there are third party solutions like XmlPrime or the .NET version of Saxon 9. The latter is available as a NuGet package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Saxon-HE/ or on Sourceforge as `SaxonHE9-8-0-7N-setup.exe` in https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/9.8/, documentation is available at http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/dotnet/dotnetapi.html.